# Reading in a filename, manipulating it then saving it

Tags: python, csv

Bascially I am reading in a file called Sounding, which has its name as '12142014_2345.csv' and I want to save it as

'12142014_2345_Averaged.csv'

Below is the code I have leading up to it.

```
basename = os.path.basename(Sounding)
basename,ext = os.path.split(basename)
    with open(os.path.join(basename+'_Averaged'+ext)) as f:
           w = csv.DictWriter(f, rows_1[0].keys())
           w.writeheader()
```

And this is my error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bud\Desktop\OWLES RECENT\Moving Average.py", line 151, in <module>
    with open(os.path.join(basename+'_Averaged'+ext)) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'_AveragedUIllinois_20131207Singular.csv'
```

I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) (to split the extension) instead of [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) (that splits last path element).
And don't forget to open the file in write mode (and check your indentation):

```
basename,ext = os.path.splitext(basename)
with open(os.path.join(basename+'_Averaged'+ext), 'w') as f:
       w = csv.DictWriter(f, rows_1[0].keys())
       w.writeheader()
```

Comment: wow I didn't even see that I didn't open it in write mode. I actually have to do it as 'ab' so that it is all written line after line in the .csv file. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, that's actually what the exception complains about: the file doesn't exist but that'd be quite ok if you'd try to open in write mode. This exception doesn't care about the name being wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the file name in the trace, you can see '_Averaged' coming before the full file name. `os.path.split` looks for the directory divider (usually slash). I think you want `os.path.splitext`, which splits the string into path and extension. Since you already have just the basename, the path will be the filename without the extension.